# How to get tag mp3 java artist album years

Tags: java, mp3, media-player, metadata

i want to know how to get information from a Local mp3  (C:/music/hello.mp3)
i try to use jLayer and MyID3, but without success!
i want the most easy solution.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [ID3's own site](http://www.id3.org/Implementations) in regards to implementations, you have three immediate choices in Java:

- [Entagged](http://entagged.sourceforge.net/developer.php), last updated in 2008
- [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic), actively maintained, but sparsely
- [Beaglebuddy](http://www.beaglebuddy.com/), last updated in 2008 (it seems).

Answer (score -1):

jid3lib.jar
http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/download.htm

Comment: It's an interesting library...but it was last updated over six years ago.